# Error in gradle Android studio: "Cannot invoke method get() on null object"

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, google-play-services

I have a projects with number of modules, each one is a separate app.
I added Firebase to one module, and since then another one's gradle cannot be sync.
I keep getting: "Cannot invoke method get() on null object", which disappear when I comment out the play-service" dependencies.
My gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27

//        multiDexEnabled true

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}
```

The top-level project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

I use gradle version 4.4 and Android plugin version 3.1.3
The error's stack

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$1$_afterResolve_closure1.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:316)
    at
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor357.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at
 groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at
 groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at
 groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at
 groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)

(another 150 lines)
```

Any suggestion will help,
Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106266/

Comment: @noogui I don't think it's the same, or at least the solution here is not the same, as I don't use the notation"plugins {"

Comment: More observation: When I remove the module that use Firebase from settings.gradle the module that use google-play-service is build and compile with no problem. When I add the Firebase using module back, the problem return.

Comment: Where do you actually include and apply the com.google.gms.google-services plugin, which I think is the source of:

`at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$1$_afterResolve_closure1.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:316)`

Comment: @ZhiQiaoIt it is in a gradle of a different module in that project. The other module use Firebase. When I remove the other module, the  first one build with no problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase dependency in Android Library: Cannot invoke method get() on null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564754/firebase-dependency-in-android-library-cannot-invoke-method-get-on-null-objec)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Thank you. Upgrading the google-services plugin to version 4.0.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: @EranShay Thanks.. It worked for me.. for me latest version of google-services is **4.2.0**. i.e `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

Answer (score 2):

if you use difference modules you must add firebase config to all android modules

therefor

- add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:x' to dependencies
- add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
- get firebase config ("google-service.json") for each android module and add to each module

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that other modules don't use Firebase, and I don't want to add them. It seems to me very aggressive of Firebase to say if you use one module in your project you must use Firebase in all of your modules.
By the way, my problem is with a Module that use "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location" but not Firebase. As soon as I comment out the "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'" from the other module it all works.

Comment: I was having the same issue after I added a new Wear module.... I did exactly what you said and it worked. I just need to edit the `package_name` inside the `google-service.json` based on the package name of the wear app. Thanks